# ER diagram (To create a new entity or not)

Tags: database, entity-relationship

I am new to ER Diagrams and currently trying to model a database of a (simplified) online shopping platform. I was wondering if product categories and model should be separate entities from the product entity, or can categories and models be considered attributes under the product entity?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "it depends" ...

It depends on your requirements, what you expect to do with the data, and if it has sense that "model" and "product_category" can be strong entities on their own.

For example, in normal conditions, I will assume that "product_category" is a strong entity... Why? My answer is that you can have product categories even if you don't have products for such categories.

Another reason to make it a strong entity could be reporting or making searches about product categories (It will be more easy for a database engine to list all "product categories" by searching a small table, instead of iterating for all available products to gather all their categories)

Conclusion: There is not good or wrong answer for this ... the model will be good if itself can answer your data requirements ...